# Set last login date

Tags: php, mysql

I use this code but its don`t work :/

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$update = DB::getInstance();
$update = ("UPDATE `users` SET `last_login` = '$date' WHERE `userid` = '" .$user->data()->id. "'");
```

Comment: Do you execute `$update`? If so what happens, error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't **execute** your query. And you have a big mistake.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$update = DB::getInstance(); #You created an instance
$update = ("UPDATE `users` SET `last_login` = '$date' WHERE `userid` = '" .$user->data()->id. "'"); #You assigned Query in the instance, This is the big mistake
```

**You should query like below**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$update = DB::getInstance();
$query = ("UPDATE `users` SET `last_login` = '$date' WHERE `userid` = '" .$user->data()->id. "'");

$update->YOUR_EXECUTE_FUNCTION($query);
```

**Note:** Here **YOUR_EXECUTE_FUNCTION()** is only for example purpose. Change it to your **execute** function

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$update = DB::getInstance();
$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `last_login` = '" . $date . "' WHERE `userid` = '" .$user->data()->id. "'";

$update->execute($query);
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DB::Execute() in ....
How i can fix that?

Comment: btw. try the lowercased `execute()` please

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$update = DB::getInstance();
$query = "UPDATE users SET last_login = $date WHERE userid = $user->data()->id";

$update->yourFunctionToUpdateHere($query);
```